# Autofac, MVC (with ActionFilters), Web.Forms - dependency resolution conflict

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, autofac

I've got a legacy Web.Forms app that been partially rewritten to MVC. MVC part uses autofac as a dependency injection container.

MVC part have custom filter defined:

```
public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    protected ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    public CustomActionFilter(ILogger logger) { Logger = logger; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Logger.Log("OnActionExecuting");
    }
}
```

It works fine when Web.Forms integration is disabled in web.config. Hovewer, when I try to use Web.Forms autofac integration, I've got the NullReferenceException related to `AutofacFilterProvider` somewhere in autofac internals ([stack trace](http://pastebin.com/nnrtUPYJ)).

- Global.asax.cs: http://pastebin.com/437Tnp0t
- web.config: http://pastebin.com/5pU6SH6c

Note that `CustomActionFilter` is registered as global filter, thus it is registered with autofac:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<CustomActionFilter>());
    }
}
```

I've tried:

1. using separate containers for MVC and Web.Forms - same result
2. Use property injection instead of constructor - same result
3. Explicitly trigger dependencies resolution on web.forms pages (like [this](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebFormsIntegration#Dependency_Injection_via_Base_Page_Class)) - worked

So, the question is, are there any way to provide behind-the-scenes dependency resolution both to MVC and web.forms part. I'm new to autofac and somewhat new to dependency injection containers in general, so I might just miss something obvious.

Update: error has nothing to do with *custom* filters. If I remove all references to custom filters the bug behavior still the same, even the stack trace.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `ContainerDisposalModule` and after that you reenable `PropertyInjectionModule` and `AttributedInjectionModule`? The `ContainerDisposalModule` shouldn't be needed because the Autofac.MVC includes a new `RequestLifetimeHttpModule` which disposes the Lifetimscope created during the request...

Comment: OK, I see now what is the problem... will you have services registered with `InstancePerHttpRequest`?

Comment: I don't think so. Right now default (`InstancePerDependency`) is used. Anyway services are intended to be lightweight, so it's unlikely we will use `InstancePerHttpRequest`.

Comment: @MdAslam I think you should post a new question about this - my problem is long resolved (and I've already moved out of .net ecosystem), so I don't think I can provide any significant help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually there are two bugs? in Autofac which causing this behavior:

**Bug #1:** As side effect of the fix of [Issue 351](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=351) the `AutofacDependencyResolver` needs to registered in the created Request bound `LifeTimeScope`s. The MVC intergration does this but the Winforms integration of course does not.

**Bug? #2:** Both the `RequestLifetimeScopeProvider` and the `ContainerProvider` stores the created `ILifetimeScope` with the same key `HttpContext.Current.Items`:

```
static ILifetimeScope LifetimeScope
{
    get { return (ILifetimeScope)HttpContext.Current.Items[typeof(ILifetimeScope)]; }
    set { HttpContext.Current.Items[typeof(ILifetimeScope)] = value; }
}
```

So there is a little bit race condition here because depending on which module gets executed first the WebForms or the MVC intergartion ILifetimeScope wins. So if the WebForms module wins the `AutofacDependencyResolver` won't be registered and you get the nice non descriptive exception.

**Fix/workaround:**

But there is an simple workaround: you just need to register the `AutofacDependencyResolver` in the `ContainerProvider` `requestLifetimeConfiguration` so no matter which one wins (WebForm vs. MVC) the `AutofacDependencyResolver` will be always registered:

```cs
var autofacDependencyResolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(autofacDependencyResolver);
_containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(container, requestContainerBuilder => 
     requestContainerBuilder.RegisterInstance(autofacDependencyResolver)
     .As<AutofacDependencyResolver>());
```