# WebForms Project with Mvc Area and Autofac IoC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, webforms, autofac

I have a WebForms project with an Mvc Area.

I have two methods in the Application_Start of the Global.asax.cs to register services with Autofac Dependency Injection respectively;

```
private void WebFormsContainer()
        {
            var webFormsContainer = new ContainerBuilder();

            webFormsContainer.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(CompanyService).Assembly)
                .Where(s => s.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();

            _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(webFormsContainer.Build());
        }
```

and also,

```
private void MvcContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(CompanyService).Assembly)
                .Where(s => s.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();

            IContainer container = builder.Build();

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        }
```

The WebForms injection appears to work but when I try the Mvc part of the app I get the error;

No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Question is how do I set up Autofac for MVC areas in a Webforms app?

Comment: What is the question? Also, the exception should name the type that lacks parameterless constructor so you should either add one or register the types required for instantiation.

Comment: @orhtej2 it's the controller in the MVC area that has no parameterless constructor.

Comment: Is it at all possible to share a single container between ASP Web Forms pages and Mvc controllers? I'd like to register some types as singletons that can be accessed by either part of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had previously tried the answer from this post;
[Autofac, MVC (with ActionFilters), Web.Forms - dependency resolution conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340594/autofac-mvc-with-actionfilters-web-forms-dependency-resolution-conflict) but I must have attempted incorrectly because I have retried it and got it to work.